# why i get promise rejection when picking an image with expo-image-picker?

Tags: javascript, react-native, exp

I want to implement image uploading feature with React Native, so i'm using [expo-image-picker](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/imagepicker/)
I have following code from the docs in react-native, Expo:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Button, Image, View } from "react-native";
import * as ImagePicker from "expo-image-picker";

export default function EditProfile() {
  const [image, setImage] = useState(null);

  const pickImage = async () => {
    // No permissions request is necessary for launching the image library
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
      allowsEditing: true,
      aspect: [4, 3],
      quality: 1,
    });

    console.log(result);

    if (!result.canceled) {
      setImage(result.assets[0].uri);
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center" }}>
      <Button title="Pick an image from camera roll" onPress={pickImage} />
      {image && (
        <Image source={{ uri: image }} style={{ width: 200, height: 200 }} />
      )}
    </View>
  );
}
```

After i have chosen an image i get this output:

```
{"assetId": null, "base64": null, "cancelled": false, "exif": null, "height": 2604, "type": "image", "uri": "file:///data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/cache/ImagePicker/9cf27130-4e9e-4917-b9aa-535af3f17453.jpeg", "width": 3472}
```

And this warning:

```
Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'result.assets[0]')
```

I tried reinstalling the package but it didn't work. I'd be grateful for any answer.

Comment: Please include the output of `console.log(result)` in your question.

Comment: take a look at this issue here , it's related to yours [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69158182/undefined-is-not-an-object-evaluating-response-assets0-react-native-react)

Comment: @Adam ,  thanks but i already tried react-native-image-crop package but after some time of  debugging i saw that it is not supported in Expo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because there's no property of **assets[0]**
result only contain below data, you can type **result.uri** directly

```
{width:720
exif:null
height:540
cancelled:false
uri:"file:///data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/cache/ImagePicker/b44b90ae-02c7-4261-96e8-0e48ba88a0ef.jpeg"
assetId:null
type:"image"
base64:null}
```